# Jquery send data to controller method from $().Load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

First try to relate the things.
I have a dynamic created div which I was loading from `$().Load()`
something like this

```
 $(elem).load("BarChart");
```

> Note: elem id dynamically created div at the same moment

untill this all working fine but now I want to send selected Data

something like this

```
       $(elem).load("BarChart",{Values: values});
```

Note: BarChart is Partial View. which is calling Controller Method but not able to find the values passed from `load`

controller Method

```
 public ActionResult BarChart(List<String> Values)
        {
            foreach (var v in Values)
            {
                lstPointSeries = Utility.GetPointSeries(Session["DbName"].ToString(), Session["AccountGroupName"].ToString(), null, AggregrationType.Total, v, null);
            }
            ViewBag.pointSeries = lstPointSeries;

            return PartialView();
        }
```

> Note: Values is null

**EDIT:**

var values are list of selected checkbox from UI. like this
something like this

> values = ["first","second","third","fourth"];

```
var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.XAxisrowCheckbox').map(function () {
            return $(this).closest('td').next().text();
        }).get();
```

Comment: is `values` you are sending is array or object format?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao see the edit

Comment: did you try stringifying the values? like `values=JSON.stringify(values)`? and just try sending `values` instead of `{Values:values}`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i tried sending only values but not by stringifying can you elaborate on it

Comment: did that work? sending just `values`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  no it also didnt work for me

Comment: how about `stringifying`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, and it works fine

Try this:

```
url = urlHelper.CommonHelper("", "About", "TestAction");
$("#TestDivId").load(url, { Values: ["aaa","bbb"] });
public ActionResult TestAction(List<string> Values) { return View(); }
```

[image]

Comment: how ? can you post your code... I am getting null values at controller

Comment: `url = urlHelper.CommonHelper("", "About", "TestAction");` `$("#TestDivId").load(url, { Values: ["aaa","bbb"] });`` public ActionResult TestAction(List<string> Values)
        {
            return View();
        }`

Comment: will check and let you know